# Slow keras fit method with 100x100 array, how can I make it faster?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

how can I make this training faster ?
when I call the fit method on a 100 x 100 matrix goes very slow

my model it's a sequential

```
h = self.model.fit(
        inputs,
        targets,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=16,
        verbose=1,
)
```

this is my matrix

```
def build(n):
    mat=np.ones(N*N)
    return mat.reshape((N,N))
```

this is the of my Qtraining

```
qt = Qtraining(model,
               env,
               n_epoch=200,
               max_memory=500,
               data_size=100,
               name='model100')
```

This is the experience method

```
def get_data(self, data_size=10):
        env_size = self.memory[0][0].shape[1]  # env_state 1d size (1st element of episode)
        mem_size = len(self.memory)
        data_size = min(mem_size, data_size)
        inputs = np.zeros((data_size, env_size)) # metti Nsize righe di 0 , e envSize elementi 0
        targets = np.zeros((data_size, self.num_actions))#
        for i, j in enumerate(np.random.choice(range(mem_size), data_size, replace=False)):
            env_state, action, reward, next_env_state, game_over = self.memory[j]
            inputs[i] = env_state
            # There should be no target values for actions not taken.
            # Thou shalt not correct actions not taken #deep (quote by Eder Santana)
            targets[i] = self.predict(env_state)
            # Q_sa = derived policy = max quality env/action = max_a' Q(s', a')
            Q_sa = np.max(self.predict(next_env_state))
            if game_over:
                targets[i, action] = reward
            else:
                # reward + gamma * max_a' Q(s', a')
                targets[i, action] = reward + self.discount * Q_sa
       
        return inputs, targets
```

---

using a 50 x 50 matrix I get 2500 cells, and in the construction of the neural network I have a 2500x2500 parameters + 2500 for a total of 6252500.
I think that slows down operations.
and there are only 3 Danse layers, the last one is size 4 because of the possible actions that are 4.
Is it possible to reduce the time of operation by adding more Danse layers?

this is my model

```
def build_model(env, **opt):
loss = opt.get('loss', 'mse')
a = opt.get('alpha', 0.24)
model = Sequential()
esize = env.maze.size
model.add(Dense(esize, input_shape=(esize,)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=a))
model.add(Dense(esize))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=a))
model.add(Dense(num_actions))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
return model
```

Comment: Hello, your `build` function seems to have an error. You should use `n` instead of `N` inside the function. Besides, I think you can directly `return np.ones(N)` to have a correct shape.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,  but I think I have identified the problem although I do not know how to improve.

Comment: I write a "problem" as an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to speed up your code:

- Use an existing framework. It appears you are doing reinforcement learning (RL). [keras-rl](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl) is an existing framework for RL which may be more efficient than your code.
- Having everything in computer memory all the time. It will speed up your code to define a smaller gameplay memory replay buffer and only use a subset of the environment that is currently relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TensorFlow GPU module. Keras is built on top of TensorFlow and it helps a lot. It is quit difficult to install, but I can help you with that. In total I got a 40x speed-up:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

VID:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IubEtS2JAiY
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHWkvEcDBO0